# Pass JS variable to PHP using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know this has been asked on here but none of the answers I found answered my question.

I have a PHP/HTML file that the users view. When they click on a button, it creates a JS variable which I would like translated into a PHP variable. Using that variable, I would like to update the contents of a div box by calling a PHP function which populates the box with info from the server.

My questions:
Can this be done with only 1 php file? Do I have to have the user reload the page after I refresh the content? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes you can do this surely.. Use ajax for that.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. PHP runs server side while javascript is on the client. To send a value to your PHP app you should POST it via HTTP.

Comment: Ya you have to post the variable then only you can access that variable

Comment: Why he has to use http reuest. He can use xmlhttp(ajax) request and sesnd the data.

Comment: POST the variable to the same page and use $REQUEST to retrieve it?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` method will give you the get and post data. Other wise you have to use the appropriate method which you used for posting the data to server.

Comment: use ajax to post the JS variable, and update the div after a successful ajax call

Comment: Post the variable to the same page using ajax, and check for the $_POST to be set and then do whatever if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the user reloading the page, but that would require AJAX. That raises the question - Does this need to work without JavaScript?

If you are happy for this to be dependant on JavaScript you could use an AJAX post, such as this using JQuery:

```
$.post( "example.php", { variableName: "example" })
  .done(function( response ) {
    $('.example-output').html( response );
  });
```

example.php would be a different .php file, in example.php you would process the value of `variableName` and produce the required markup, which would be displayed in the original page. If you need this to work without JavaScript then I would suggest reloading the page.